# HTML How to make a video background adjust/crop depending on the screen size?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've made this site but when I viewed it on my phone and on other screen size device, it would look weird.
This one for example: [image]

I just manually adjusted the video background by trial and error to fit my screen and I'm guessing that's why it would only look the intended way when viewed from the screen this size. I wanted to make it so that it would adjust or at least crop the background when viewed on different screens.

HTML

```
        <div class="homebackground">>
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
            <source src="src/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#myVideo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 90.1%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -286px;
    margin-top: 34px;
  }
.homebackground {
    display: block;
    margin: 20%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```